# Как правильно составить запрос установку нового статуса в ВК?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я пробую делать так

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("status.set", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.STATUS, "New status"));
```

но статус просто очищается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, в VKApiConst.STATUS находится неправильное название поля для текста, нужного не приходит и статус стирается. Параметр должен называться "text".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!! Вы были правы, правильно так: VKRequest request = new VKRequest("status.set", VKParameters.from("text","New status"));